Find MAC addresses of connected Wii Remotes
I want to connect one or more Wii remotes for reading their inputs. From the output of cat /proc/bus/input/devices I can extract data like Sysfs and the input Handlers. The Handers information I use to read from the corresponding input device (e.g. from /dev/input/event17). My question: how can I get the corresponding MAC addresses?
The output for one remote looks like:
N: Name="Nintendo Wii Remote"
P: Phys=
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:3/0005:057E:0306.0009/input/input29
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event17 js0 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=200003
B: KEY=10800000 0 1003000000000006 0 0 168000000000 0
B: FF=107030000 0

(Once a remote is inactive for a while I like to disconnect it via bluetoothctl disconnect {MAC-address}, but I need to distinguish between multiple remotes... And I don't want to disconnect the wrong remote...)

Okay, I just found a solution accidentally by myself: Inside a parent path of the Sysfs directory (in my case under /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:3/0005:057E:0306.0009/) there is a file uevent which contains the line
HID_UNIQ=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
with the MAC address I was searching for!
